# Option to open websites from explorer in a new window instead of a new tab

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, taskbar, internet-explorer-8

Is there an option in control panel or a registry-setting, that lets windows explorer open requests for websites in a new internet-explorer-window instead of a new tab in an existing internet-explorer-instance?

I'm mostly interested for an option for the windows 7 task-manager. If I right click on the explorer icon and then click a link ("pinned" or "frequent"), I would like that internet explorer opens a new explorer window and not opens the page in a new tab of an existing internet explorer window. If there is an option to make this the default behaviour for all windows-explorer actions, I am even more interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select **Tools > Internet Options > General > Tabs > Settings** you get the following dialog:

[image: open links from other programs]

Try setting the radio button to the "A new window" option.